# Probability problem socks

Tags: probability

A drawer has 7 different pairs of socks. Each sock is taken randomly and without replacement until the first pair is found.  What is the probability of having the first pair until the 8th extraction?

My answer is $\frac{2^7}{\binom{14}{7}}=0.037$, is my answer right?

Comment: The last sentence containing the question is worded strangely. Is the word "not" missing? "What is the probability of NOT having the first pair until the 8th extration?". In that case you are correct: $2^7$ denotes the number to choose either sock 0 or sock 1 from each pair, and $\binom{14}7$ denotes the way to choose $7$ socks from $14$ socks. Both are unorded pickings, so it all checks out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability is
$$\frac{14}{14} \times \frac{12}{13} \times \frac {10}{12} \cdots \times \frac{2}{8},$$
where there are seven fractions, each of which refers to the probability of picking a sock from an un-picked pair at each step.

This does indeed rearrange to $\frac{2^7}{\binom{14}{7}}$.